# How to stub request/response in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using RSpec's mock/stub, how do I write a unit test for the `find_by_id` method?

I want to use RSpec, not WebMock or VCR. How do I create a stub for the request/response?

```
class RapidApiClient
  HOST_URL = 'https://brianiswu-open-brewery-db-v1.p.rapidapi.com/breweries'
  API_KEY  = 'private_api_key'

   def request_api(url)
    Excon.get(
      url,
      headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Host' => HOST_URL,
        'X-RapidAPI-Key' => 'API_KEY'
      }
    )
  end

 def find_by_id(id)
    response = request_api("#{HOST_URL}/#{id}")
    return nil if response.status != 200
    JSON.parse(response.body)
 end  
end
```

The response is:

```
[
{"id":4 , "name":"Ban Brewing Company" , "brewery_type":"micro", "city":"Tulsa" , "state":"OK"}
{"id":44,"name":"Tab Brewing" "brewery_type":"micro", "city":"Birmingham", "state":"MO"}
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can stub the `request_api` method itself so that you don't have to make the HTTP request using something like this:

```
expect_any_instance_of(RapidApiClient)
    .to receive(:request_api)
    .and_return([
                  {"id":4 , "name":"Ban Brewing Company" , "brewery_type":"micro", "city":"Tulsa" , "state":"OK"}
                  {"id":44,"name":"Tab Brewing" "brewery_type":"micro", "city":"Birmingham", "state":"MO"}
                ])
```

if you want to stub the actaul request/response.

You can sub the `get` method of `Excon` library like this:

```
expect(Excon)
.to receive(:get)
.and_return(Excon::Response.new(
     :status => 200,
     :body => '[{"id":4 , "name":"Ban Brewing Company","brewery_type":"micro", "city":"Tulsa" , "state":"OK"},{"id":44,"name":"Tab Brewing" "brewery_type":"micro", "city":"Birmingham", "state":"MO"}]'
    ))
```

Comment: thanks , but this isn't really testing my code, is it?

Comment: "How do I create a stub for the request/response?" you asked this in your question, you also mentioned you are unit testing `find_by_id` and in unit testing, we don't usually care for other dependencies. You should verify request response when you are unit testing `request_api` not `find_by_id`.

Comment: I'm really sorry. my intention was to test the request/response. but somehow, I worded it wrong. I apologize.I can open a new question, if needed.

Comment: What do you actaully want to test, looking at your request_api method, it is just sending a request. You said you don't want to use `vcr/webmock`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I would like to test both of the functions. but I'm not sure how all of the mock/stub works in rspec. how would I mock my request_api method. like you said in your previous comment, "i should verify request/response, when I'm unit testing request_api". I' m a beginner in ruby, so pardon my confusion.

Comment: Since your `request_api` method doesn't encapsulate any additional logic on your end, but just a method call to third party library, there is nothing much to test. Like I said before, when unit testing `find_by_id`, you should stub the `request_api` method, and when unit testing `request_api` method, you can just stub the `Excon` libaray `get` method, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I opened a new question for this. but I wasn't clear about one last thing.  so in my test method. I should let subject be excon, then write allow statement. in your response , did you mean expect or allow for statment 2 below. can you update it with full test?  = > 1. let (subject) {' Excon'} 2. allow(Excon)
.to receive(:get)
.and_return(Excon::Response.new(
     :status => 200,
     :body => '[{{"id":44,"name":"Tab" "type":"mic", "city":"", "state":"MO"}]'))